# Убрать border у всех элементов

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как убрать border у всех div кроме нажатого?

```js
function check(number) {
document.getElementById('divstol['+number+']').style.border = '3px solid #9C27B0';
}
```

```css
.divk {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="divstol[1]" class="divk" onclick="check(1)">
  1
</div>
<div id="divstol[2]" class="divk" onclick="check(2)">
  2
</div>
<div id="divstol[3]" class="divk" onclick="check(3)">
  3
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так например:

```js
function check(number) {
  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.divk')).forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.border = '1px solid #ced4da';
  })
  document.getElementById('divstol['+number+']').style.border = '3px solid #9C27B0';
}
```

```css
.divk {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="divstol[1]" class="divk" onclick="check(1)">
  1
</div>
<div id="divstol[2]" class="divk" onclick="check(2)">
  2
</div>
<div id="divstol[3]" class="divk" onclick="check(3)">
  3
</div>
```

Comment: Тогда border в 1px добавляется ко всем div элементам на странице

Comment: @Vladislav заменил код

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает.